# Is there another way to do repaint() in java?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, repaint

I learned that repaint() wasn't an actual method that repaints the screen. Rather, it is a request to the JVM to do that. However, out of curiosity and for future references, is there a way to take the repainting task into your own hands so that you could stack a bunch of repainting functions near each other without worrying about coalescence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you could implement your own [`RepaintManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html).